# Merge multiple CSV into one DataFrame with filename as column name

Tags: python, pandas

I have a number of txt files in a directory that I'd like to combine.The following is an example of three files named df_A, df_B and df_c:

```
df_A
       0  1    2
0  James  1  yes
1   Jake  3   No
2   Jane  2  Yes

df_B
       0  1    2
0   Jane  2   No
1    Job  6   No
2  James  1  Yes

df_C
       0  1    2
0   Jack  4   No
1  Jenny  7  Yes
2  James  1   No
3   John  9  Yes
```

AndI'd like the final dataframe to look like this:

```
ID  Name    df_A    df_B    df_C

1   James   Yes     Yes     No
3   Jake    No      NA      NA
2   Jane    Yes     No      NA
6   Job     NA      Yes     NA
4   Jack    NA      NA      No
7   Jenny   NA      NA      Yes
9   John    NA      NA      Yes
```

this is the code I have thus far...

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Name', 'ID'])

for filename in os.listdir('/path'):
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        course = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]

        new_df = pd.concat([combined_df,pd.DataFrame(columns=[course])])
        data = pd.read_csv(filename, sep="\t", header=None)

        for i in data[data.columns[1]]:
            if i not in new_df['ID']:
                new_df['ID'].append(i)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For these three dataframes, just assign column names. The last column should be unique. Then, call `pd.concat` + `groupby` for your output.

```
dfA.columns = ['Name', 'ID', 'df_A']
dfB.columns = ['Name', 'ID', 'df_B']
dfC.columns = ['Name', 'ID', 'df_C']

pd.concat([dfA, dfB, df3])\
      .groupby('Name', as_index=False, sort=False).first()\
      .set_index('ID').fillna('')

     Name df_A df_B df_C
ID                      
1   James  yes  Yes   No
3    Jake   No          
2    Jane  Yes   No     
6     Job        No     
4    Jack             No
7   Jenny            Yes
9    John            Yes
```

---

In a general case, say you have `df_list`. You can then assign column names in a loop.

```
df_list = [dfA, dfB, dfC, ...]
for i, df in enumerate(df_list):
    df.columns = ['Name', 'ID', 'df_{}'.format(chr(ord('A') + i))]

pd.concat(df_list).groupby('Name', 
        as_index=False, sort=False).first().set_index('ID')
```

Comment: Your code works but I'd really love to avoid manipulating the files. So, I thought of tweaking your code. I did this: `import os
import pandas as pd

finalDF = pd.DataFrame()

for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        target = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, delimiter=' ')
        df.columns = ['Name', 'ID', target]
        finalDF = pd.concat([finalDF, df]).groupby('Name', as_index=False, sort=False).first().set_index('ID').fillna('')
        `

Comment: @AndyG Feel free to edit my answer with whatever works for you, and mark it accepted (upvote it as well, if you wish).

Comment: @AndyG I'm sorry, I can't understand your code as you've pasted it. If this code works, then open a new post with your follow up question, please?

Answer (score 3):

```
import os
import pandas as pd

combinedDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name','ID'])

for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, delimiter=' ')
        df.columns=['Name','ID',filename[:-4]]
        combinedDF = combinedDF.merge(df, on=['Name', 'ID'], how='outer')
```